# find Javascript object length

Tags: javascript

Im trying to find the length of the report_data(object) key using the below code..but for some reasons it yields value 3.

```
a={report_freq: "daily", report_item_num: 2, report_num: 39, report_data: "{}"}
Object {report_freq: "daily", report_item_num: 2, report_num: 39, report_data: "{}"}
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.report_data).length
3
```

for more clarity I have the image.

[image]

Comment: You mean keys of json object?

Comment: `report_data` is a string, not an object

Comment: even if its a string..WHy does it yield a value of 3?

Comment: JDB answered your question below :)

Answer (score 6):

`a.report_data` is a string with three properties:

- `0`, representing the first character (`"{"`).
- `1`, representing the second character (`"}"`).
- and `length`, representing the length of the string (`2`).

It's a little counter-intuitive, if you come from other languages, that `0` and `1` are properties, but in Javascript array elements are properties just like all other properties, and "regular" properties can be accessed using array syntax (aka "[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)"):

```
// "array elements"
a.report_data[0]        === "{";
a.report_data[1]        === "}";
// or...
a.report_data["0"]      === "{";
a.report_data["1"]      === "}";

// "normal" properties
a.report_data.length    === 2;
// or...
a.report_data["length"] === 2;
```

These are all property names, and, thus, when you ask for an array of property names for your string, you get:

```
["0", "1", "length"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the length of the actual *string value*, then you simply want to use `report_data.length`, as demonstrated here:

```js
var a = {
  report_freq: "daily",
  report_item_num: 2,
  report_num: 39,
  report_data: "{}"
};

console.log(a.report_data.length)
```

Your current code includes this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.report_data).length
```

If you look at the docs for [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames), you'll see the following description:

> Object.getOwnPropertyNames() returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable and non-enumerable properties found directly upon obj.

So, in this case, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.report_data)` returns an array containing the keys found on the string, and there happens to be 3 of them.